# No me abre anaconda navigator en Windows y creo que es porque tenía Spyder antes

Tags: anaconda

> Soy muy novato con esto de los scripts, y he intentado distintas soluciones que he visto en problemas parecidos pero en mi caso parece que tengo otro error y no me valen esas soluciones.

He instalado Spyder hace 2 días, seleccionando lo de "add to path", y ahora he instalado anaconda sin el "add to path" y se instala bien, pero al abrir el navigator no se me abre. En la terminal lo pruebo desde el mismo directorio usando anaconda-navigator y tampoco. En el prompt de anaconda (que sí se me abre, como jupiter) también he probado pero nada.

Lo que hice fue desinstalar anaconda y spyder en *agregar y quitar programas* de windows directamente e instalar anaconda de nuevo.

También instalé hace dos días visual studio code, pero eso creo que no es el problema.

Os muestro el error que me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado también en el directorio sin entrar en scripts, pero tampoco se abre.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido que funcione:

He actualizado a windows 11 y ahora si se abre. También pienso que podría haber reiniciado en windows 10 a ver si así se solucionaba pero no lo hice.

Si a alguien le pasa como a mi, que tenia Spyder y luego instala anaconda y no le abre, mi otra solución iba a ser restablecer el ordenador para que se limpien todos los archivos e instalar anaconda desde cero. Mirad por si acaso que tengáis la partición  para el windows en el disco duro si el pc es de segunda mano, no vaya a ser que hayan cambiado el disco duro, o la partición se haya borrado. Por cierto, no lo sabía pero no se necesita disco externo con windows para instalarlo después de formatear ni nada como antiguamente.

Comment: En realidad se me abrió el navigator, pero al abrir Spyder me salia el mismo error. Creo que se debe tambien a haer utilizado pip para instalar el pyqt5 etc. Parece que hay que utilizar conda install para no fastidiar la instalación.

Comment: Lo arreglé entonces restableciendo el Wiindows a fabrica y ya me va todo perfecto, asi que a disfrutarlo! Gracias y espero que sirva de ayuda a alguien.